# How store Hibernate Envers audit tables into a different database?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Hibernate Envers can store audit tables into a different schema or catalog but could you tell me if it is possible to configure Envers to store them into a different database (another persistence unit) ?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not currently possible. However often a `catalog` is a synonym for `database` (depending on the database, of course). So maybe that's an option to consider.

Comment: Hi adamw, I have this compilation error when I tried to extends DefaultRevisionEntity, do you know why ? If I copy fields into my class and disable inheritance it works fine. "Unable to retrieve inheritance class org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity"

Comment: Never saw this before, sorry